# Search tableview row click to go details view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have implement UISearchController in my HomeController.By this way

```
SearchTableViewController *searchResults = (SearchTableViewController *)self.controller.searchResultsController;
[self addObserver:searchResults forKeyPath:@"myResult" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
searchResults.rootHomeController=_homeController;
[self presentViewController:self.controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

My Search value showing well in SearchTableViewController.Now I need to go details after SearchTableViewController UITableView cell click i tried by this way but not working.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                @"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
AlbumSongListController *detailSongList=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AlbumSongListControllerID"];
    [self presentViewController:detailSongList animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I need to pass navigation controller so that i can back to search controller

Comment: can you elobrate  need to pass navigation controller so that i can back to search controller

Comment: when i click on search tableview row i can go details view fine .but i want to add navigation back button so that i can comeback to searchviewtable   controller

Comment: plz check my answer @aDowla

Comment: then in this place `[self presentViewController:detailSongList animated:YES completion:nil];` use [Self.navigation Controller pushviewcontroller: detailSongList animated :YES];

Answer (score 0):

pass your result one view controller to another by declaring a varialble like:

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
                    let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DestViewController") as!  DestViewController
                    resultViewController.result = self.result
                    self.presentViewController(resultViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: questioner tagged as objective C at the same time how do we create `result` in `resultViewController`, can you updated the answer with details

Comment: declare a result variable to your destination view controller and pass your source view controller result to destination view ontroller

Comment: @ChiragPatel - I know biddy, assume that qustioner is fresher how he anaylize your answer is corerct

Answer (score 0):

plz use this code in app delegate

```
 -(BOOL) application: (UIApplication * ) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary * ) launchOptions {
    UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
        @ "Main"
        bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]
    ];

    HomeVcController * HomeVcControllerOb = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @ "HomeVcControllerID"];

    UINavigationController * navController = [
        [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: HomeVcControllerOb
    ];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;

}
```

and hidden NavigationBar on homeVWcontroller

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

then after just use this

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
    @ "Main"
    bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]
];

AlbumSongListController * detailSongList = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @ "AlbumSongListControllerID"];

[self presentViewController: detailSongList animated: YES completion: nil];
```

and in AlbumSongListController show navigation bar

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:No animated:YES];
```

Comment: [self presentViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];   this code is working but still not showing back button

Comment: Yes showing nevigation bar .But not showing back button

Comment: @aDowla check it now.

Comment: Not working still.A black screen coming front after search button click

Comment: SearchTableViewController first view controller or you are useing other view controller.

Comment: HomeController is first controller.in home controller search button click UISearchtableview appearing in front of homecontroller

Comment: So plz use HomeController ob where i use SearchTableViewController . it will work for you and also set self.window.rootViewController = passcodeNavigationController

Comment: @aDowla what happened ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to present a navigation controller with  SearchTableViewController as root in your HomeController. Thus you can perform navigations.

i.e. on click of table cell in SearchTableViewController (didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate), push the detail view controller using [self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller] , you will get back navigation to SearchTableViewController by doing so.